# Wrong value with LM2937

Tags: voltage-regulator, schematics

[image]

I designed a PCB accoridng to the schematic above and here is the PCB:
[image]

It's not working as it' supposed to be.
After LM2937ET-10 (package SOT-223), I'm supposed to get +10 between pin 3 and pin 2 of this chip.
But when I put my 12v on input, I only measure 3V as output instead of 10. Is there something wrong?

Comment: From [reading the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2937.pdf), you seem to be missing a bigger capacitor on the LM2937's output. 22 nF won't be enough.

Comment: @Renan I suspect that is a typo on schematics. I don't think there is such thing as 22 nF polarized capacitor. Besides, the pads on PCB are obviously for large electrolytic.

Comment: Indeed I did not paid attention to this ;( I tested with a 10uF cap but I have like a big voltage drop from 12 to 3V when I measure my input and I don't know why. This is really strange

Comment: Apparently, you didn't pay attention to many things. See an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PCB routing for ICL7660 is wrong. Input and output are reversed, which I suspect simply shorts the output of LM2937.

Also, it is bad idea to use internal connection between tab and ground pins of LM2937. Either leave tab floating or (better) connect them together, exactly as datasheet recommends

Comment: Are you sure about my ICL7660 ? Pin 8 in voltage input and pin 5 voltage output; isn't it? In my routing, i followed this

Comment: The pin numbers are correct. The pads are mixed up. You've connected input to pad 5 and output to 8

Comment: Indeed :( waste of money here. Do you recommend any other change before i order new version?

Comment: Only ground routing for LM2937, as I already mentioned. I presume that DPDT is used to switch second wire between GND and V+, although I don't see any output traces, so can't be sure. It seems it should switch the lower pin of the pot instead, for + output to be adjustable as well. In fact, if you use DPDT then why do you need negative converter at all? You can just swap the wires with it.

Comment: I know it's strange the output will be the curseur of potentiometer. I use the switch to select if I want to have - 10v or +10v then the potentiometer is used to have between 0 and +10v or 0 and - 10v

Comment: I understand that. I am just surprised that there is no trace from the wiper. And if the output goes out of your circuit then it does not matter which wire is gnd, only matters which is + and which is -.

Comment: I see. This is because its not soldered on the board so I put a terminal block with 2 wires in (- and + voltage) and the 3 wire is the output which goes to the potentiometer

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. The header marked "2kOhm" is confusing.